# Carrierwave upload to Amazon S3 from a rake task: can't get upload to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rake, carrierwave

I am trying to generate a csv file in a rake task and...

1. Email it
2. Upload it to Amazon s3.

Here is the task.

```
     desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"

     require 'csv'

     task :send_report => :environment do
      file = Baseline.to_csv
      ReportMailer.database_report(file).deliver_now
      Report.create!(:data => file)
     end
```

The generation of the csv file and attachment to the email works fine (not shown). Its the carrierwave upload that isn't working. Please note that I have other uploaders for other models and they work fine so my bucket settings are correct.

Here are the other files.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :data, ReportUploader
end
```

and

```
 class ReportUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   storage :fog

   def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

   def extension_white_list
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png csv xls)
   end

 end
```

I have tried various permutations such as store! with not luck. I should add that if I look at the database, the new report is being created (and the data attribute is "nil", with no upload in sight)

Thanks